# Find Reference and Copy All Matching Answers to a Specific Column

Tags: excel, copy, find, range, vba

I have made a calendar with the dates throughout the year which I will use to register new objects every month. The month itself isn't important - I just am using month as a reference to find the correct range of dates so at the moment looks.

```
FEB  01/02/2014
FEB  02/02/2014 
FEB  03/02/2014
FEB  04/02/2014
FEB  05/02/2014
MAR  01/03/2014
MAR  02/03/2014
JUN  02/06/2014
Jun  03/06/2014
```

The whole year is in place. I have a drop down menu on the first page detailing the month, I would like a macro that uses the month selected as a reference and then copies all the dates associated with that month to a separate column.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are these two separate columns? In other words - is `FEB` one column, and `01/02/2014` another column? What bit do you have a problem with: finding the `FEB` values, finding the corresponding dates, copying them, or pasting them? Did you make any attempt to record a macro to get you started? That's usually a good way to get a rough idea...

Comment: Yes they are two separate columns basically I want to select and copy all dates with the same reference. I am trying to do this using filters and recording it but am not sure it will stay generic when I change the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should be close - adapt as needed. It was not written for efficiency - unless you have many thousands of items to copy, this will take "no time at all". The `Application.ScreenUpdating` trick stops the screen from flickering (and makes it faster) during the update.

```
Option Compare Text

Sub moveStuff()
Dim rLabel As Range
Dim rLabelSource As Range

Dim rDestination As Range
Dim c, L

' first label:
Set rLabel = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("source").Range("A2")
' extend all the way down:
Set rLabel = Range(rLabel, rLabel.End(xlDown))

Set rLabelSource = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("destination").Range("A1")
Set rLabelSource = Range(rLabelSource, rLabelSource.End(xlToRight))

Application.ScreenUpdating = false

' labels in the top row:
For Each L In rLabelSource.Cells
' write results in the next row down:
  Set rDestination = L.Offset(1, 0)
  For Each c In rLabel.Cells
    If c.Value = L.Value Then
      rDestination.Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
      Set rDestination = rDestination.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
  Next c
Next L

Application.ScreenUpdating = true

End Sub
```

In this case, dates and labels are in the sheet called "source":

[image]

And the destination sheet (with labels in the top row, and copied dates appearing below them) in sheet called "destination":

[image]

Obviously there are many ways to make this cleaner (clear all the space below the labels in `destination` before copying, so no old values are left behind, for example). And in "real" code you would add error handling, etc.

This should get you going though.